# What is wrong with this reasoning about free modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be any set. Let $F(A)$ be the free $R$-module of base $A$ and the map $i: A \to F(A)$ be such that $i(a) = a$. Then for any $R$-module $M$, and a map $g:A \to M$, we can find an unique map $f: F(A) \to M$ by defining it as $f(a) = 0$ for $a \notin A$, and $f(a) = g(a)$ for $a \in A$. Then, we have $f(i(a)) = f(a) = g(a)$.

I think I might have misunderstood something here because it seems too easy to define the unique map $f$. Also, by defining $i(a) = a$, we need to have $A \subseteq F(A)$, and I am guessing that it need not be so? However, I just starting reading the section on Free Modules in Dummit & Foot (3rd Ed) and they defined $i$ as the inclusion map, which I take it to mean $i(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that $F(A)$ and $i$ is the free module on $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the characterization of a free module says „map“ an $R$-linear map is meant, and the function you define is not linear.